# Is Hinduism.SE right place to ask questions related to Sanskrit language?

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked for some particular type of resource for learning Sanskrit, a mod pointed out that it's off topic? 
I don't feel it's off topic, since Hinduism.SE is substantially small. To have more related sites we must be a bit more open initially since Sanskrit.SE doesn't exists as of now. 
My another point is, the whole Hinduism is based on literature in Sanskrit language it seems less sense to say it has no relation with Hinduism.